# how to start the master node of a spark cluster from R on windows?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

[Chapter 6: "Clusters"](https://therinspark.com/clusters.html#clusters-standalone) from the book "mastering spark with R", shows how to start the master node of a Spark standalone cluster from R:

```
# Retrieve the Spark installation directory
spark_home <- spark_home_dir()
# Build paths and classes
spark_path <- file.path(spark_home, "bin", "spark-class")
# Start cluster manager master node #ko on windows ?!
system2(spark_path, "org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master", wait = FALSE)
```

unlike [this](https://rlang.hatenablog.jp/entry/2019/09/19/215117) example, showing that the last command is working on linux, 
on my windows machine the command run with no warning but without any effect:
nothing is printed out in the console, and no web interface is served at http://127.0.0.1:8080/

I could but succesfully start a master node from a windows cmd prompt like this:

```
set SPARH_HOME=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\spark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7
cmd /k %SPARH_HOME%\conf\spark-env.cmd
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

and add some worker node with

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker -i 10.0.75.1 -p 7077
```

but then when connecting to the master from R, with :

```
sc <- spark_connect(spark_home = spark_install_find(version="2.4.3")$sparkVersionDir,master = "spark://localhost:7077")
if(file.exists("codes_ages")) unlink("codes_ages", TRUE)
codes.ages.df <- spark_read_csv(sc,name = "codes_ages", path = paste0(datadir,"/age.txt"), header = FALSE, delimiter = " ")
```

either the first or the third command never lasts ... (datadir is set and age.txt is made of about 20 short lines.)

So how to start the master from R or how to conect to a (local) master node ?